# Accessing exchange data in Brightway2 database object

Tags: brightway

I have a question about accessing exchange data using the Brightway database object. Suppose I have `import Brightway2 as bw` and am in a project where there is an LCI database:

```
[In]  bw.databases
[Out] Brightway2 databases metadata with 2 objects:
          biosphere3
          ecoinvent 3_2 APOS
```

I can get information on activities:

```
[In]  ei32 = bw.Database('ecoinvent 3_2 APOS')
      someActivity = ei32.get('00c71af952a1248552fc2bfa727bb6b5')
      someActivity
[Out] 'market for transport, freight, inland waterways, barge with reefer, cooling' (ton kilometer, GLO, None)
```

It seems I have access to the following data:

```
[In]   list(someActivity)
[Out]  ['database',
        'production amount',
        'name',
        'reference product',
        'classifications',
        'activity',
        'location',
        'filename',
        'parameters',
        'code',
        'authors',
        'paramters',
        'comment',
        'flow',
        'type',
        'unit',
        'activity type']
```

Notice that there is no `'exchanges'`. In fact, while this works:

```
[In]   someActivity.get('location')
[Out]  'GLO'
```

or, equivalently:

```
[In]   someActivity['location']
[Out]  'GLO'
```

Changing `'location'` for `'exchanges'` yields nothing (first syntax) or a key error (second syntax).

And yet [I *have* seen this syntax](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-io/src/02f4bd990d77e8baef168f7fd3c7d455765d0a4b/bw2io/strategies/ecospold2.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#ecospold2.py-158) in Brightway code:

```
exchanges = ds.get('exchanges', [])
```

For now, my only way for accessing exchange data is to `.load` the database (which loads the entire database in a dictionary), create an activity key, and call exchanges as follows:

```
[In]  ei32Loaded = ei32.load()
      activities = sorted(ei32Loaded.keys())
      ei32Loaded[activities[42]]['exchanges']
[Out] [{'activity': '0fb6238a-e252-4d19-a417-c569ce5e2729', 'amount': xx,       
         ...}]
```

It works fine, but I know the exchange data is in the database, so I'm sure there must exist a method to get to it without loading. At the very least, I'd like to know why `someActivity.get('exchanges', [])` does not work for me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brightway2 uses a SQLite database to store LCI data (at least most of the time - other backends are possible, but SQLite is the default option). In the SQLite database, there are two tables, `ActivityDataset` and `ExchangeDataset`. An `ActivityDataset` describes an object in the supply chain graph (not strictly limited to transforming activities), and `ExchangeDataset` describes a numerical relationship between two `ActivityDataset`s. See their [schema definition](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-data/src/e80978eeae40975a90f31db90207e8cfed56ce3d/bw2data/backends/peewee/schema.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).

When you use `Database('foo').get('bar')` or `get_activity(('foo', 'bar')), you create an [Activity][2], which is a proxy object for interacting with the database. The`Activity`object exposes a number of useful methods, and handles some "magic" - for example, updating an`ActivityDataset`` should also update the search index, which is a completely separate database.

Instantiating an `Activity` loads the data that is in the `ActivityDataset` row. There are no real requirements or limits on what can be included, but one thing which is definitely not included are exchanges. Exchanges are loaded lazily, i.e. only when needed.

Some of the useful methods that `Activity` includes are exchange filters. For example, [.technosphere()](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-data/src/e80978eeae40975a90f31db90207e8cfed56ce3d/bw2data/backends/peewee/proxies.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#proxies.py-189) returns an iterator over all exchanges for which this `Activity` is the `output`, and the exchange type is `technosphere`. In LCA parlance, `.technosphere()` are the technosphere inputs for the activity. Similarly, [.upstream()](https://bitbucket.org/cmutel/brightway2-data/src/e80978eeae40975a90f31db90207e8cfed56ce3d/bw2data/backends/peewee/proxies.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#proxies.py-207) exposes the exchanges which *consume* this activity. `Activity` also includes:

- `.exchanges()`: All exchanges for which this activity is an output.
- `.biosphere()`: All exchanges for which this activity is an output, and are of the type `biosphere`.
- `.production()`: All exchanges for which this activity is an output, and are of the type `production`.

All these methods are iterators - they won't retrieve data from the database until they are iterated over. These are also *methods*, not *data attributes* of the activity, i.e. they are not accessed like `foo['technosphere']`, but rather `foo.technosphere()`.

Exchange types are used to determine where and in which matrices the numeric exchange values are to be placed during an LCA computation.

The referenced case where `exchanges = ds.get('exchanges', [])` appears in the in the IO library, where data is being imported and processed, but is not yet linked by `ExchangeDataset`s or stored in the SQLite database at all - when importing and processing inventory data, the data is a plain Python dictionary, and not a fancy combination of `Activity`s, `Exchange`s, etc.

Comment: OK, but given I have a specific exchange in mind (e.g. I know what the `input` and `output` are), is there a function to "get" the exchange directly? Right now, I do this by (1) `get`ting the activity referenced in the `output`, (2) iterating over all exchanges until the `input` matches.

Comment: There isn't, and won't be, a function in brightway for getting an exchange by an input and output. First of all, there can be multiple exchanges with the same input and output. You could, however, import `ExchangeDataset` from `bw2data.backends.default.schema` and query that directly.